# Cannot log into Incode Platform

Tags: isis

After I build Incode Platform successfully, I am unable to login with sven/pass or any password combination I can think off. The following error is logged

```
22:31:49,645  [ShiroAuthenticatorOrAuthorizor qtp1315447704-15 ERROR]  Unable to authenticate
```

org.apache.shiro.authc.DisabledAccountException
        at org.isisaddons.module.security.shiro.IsisModuleSecurityRealm.doGetAuthenticationInfo(IsisModuleSecurityRealm.java:78)
        at org.apache.shiro.realm.AuthenticatingRealm.getAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticatingRealm.java:568)
        at org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator.doSingleRealmAuthentication(ModularRealmAuthenticator.java:180)
        at org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator.doAuthenticate(ModularRealmAuthenticator.java:267)
        at org.apache.shiro.authc.AbstractAuthenticator.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticator.java:198)
        at org.apache.shiro.mgt.AuthenticatingSecurityManager.authenticate(AuthenticatingSecurityManager.java:106)
        at org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.login(DefaultSecurityManager.java:270)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.login(DelegatingSubject.java:256)
        at org.apache.isis.security.shiro.ShiroAuthenticatorOrAuthorizor.authenticate(ShiroAuthenticatorOrAuthorizor.java:151)
        at org.apache.isis.core.runtime.authentication.standard.AuthenticationManagerStandard.authenticate(AuthenticationManagerStandard.java:111)
        at org.apache.isis.viewer.wicket.viewer.integration.wicket.AuthenticatedWebSessionForIsis.authenticate(AuthenticatedWebSessionForIsis.java:73)
        at org.apache.wicket.authroles.authentication.AuthenticatedWebSession.signIn(AuthenticatedWebSession.java:66)
        at org.apache.wicket.authroles.authentication.panel.SignInPanel.signIn(SignInPanel.java:210)
        at org.apache.wicket.authroles.authentication.panel.SignInPanel.access$100(SignInPanel.java:46)
        at org.apache.wicket.authroles.authentication.panel.SignInPanel$SignInForm.onSubmit(SignInPanel.java:305)
        at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.delegateSubmit(Form.java:1313)
        at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.process(Form.java:976)
        at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.StatelessForm.process(StatelessForm.java:100)
        at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:797)
        at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:708)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:258)
        at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:216)
        at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:241)
        at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:234)
        at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:895)
        at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
        at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
        at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
        at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)

Not sure what the problem is and what I can do to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

No problem. I used the wrong AppManifest. Correct one is  mvn -pl webapp jetty:run \
         -Disis.appManifest=domainapp.appdefn.DomainAppAppManifestWithFixtures

Answer (score 0):

Yep. The default appmanifest sets up only the security module, so you would be able to log in using isis-module-security-admin/pass but that's all. Using the security admin you could of course set up another user... But that's what the other manifest with its fixture does anyway.